# Spring boot Auto connection to database

Tags: database, spring-boot, postgresql-9.3

How can spring boot automatically connect to db once DB is up after being down for a while. My spring boot application is not able to connect to the database after bringing DB from down to Up.

Comment: Is it online during startup?

Comment: Yes my spring boot app was up and running, but because of some issue DB got down & connection got lost. Now when we brought DB up, the app was not connecting to the DB. Then we had to restart the app to establish the DB connection through spring boot aap. How can we handle this auto configuration scenario where it could automatically connects to the DB.